# Redireccionamiento desde el routing en Symfony

Tags: symfony, i18n

Tengo un routing en mi proyecto Symfony que apunta a distintos controladores, en distintas rutas, así:

```
# GLOBAL DE LA APLICACIÓN
entry_point:
  path: /
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index}
  options:
    expose: true

# PARTE ADMIN
admin_index:
  path: /admin
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin\Admin:index}

admin_sec:
  path: /admin
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin\Admin:sec}

#PARTE PUBLICA
user_index:
  path: /user
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User\User:index}
# GLOBAL DE LA APLICACIÓN
entry_point:
  path: /
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index}
  options:
    expose: true

# PARTE ADMIN
admin_index:
  path: /admin
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin\Admin:index}

admin_sec:
  path: /admin
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin\Admin:sec}

#PARTE PUBLICA
user_index:
  path: /user
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User\User:index}
```

Para poder usar i18n he puesto, en el routing de app/config, lo siguiente:

```
Redireccion_por_defecto:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /es
        permanent: true

router:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix: /{_locale}
    requirements:
      _locale: es|en|fr|it|pt|de|ca
```

Se trata de que, cuando se llame a una ruta, el redireccionador añada el prefijo `_locale` que, como veis, lo he puesto como requerimiento.

En config.yml he habilitado el translator, así:

```
parameters:
    locale: es
    default_locale: es

framework:
    #esi: ~
    translator:
      fallbacks: ['%locale%']
      enabled: true
```

Cuando tecleo **localhost:8000**, todo va bien. Automáticamente "recrea" la ruta como **localhost:8000/es**, y se va al correspondiente controlador y muestra la vista.
Sin embargo, si tecleo **localhost:8000/user**, no lo reconstruye a **localhost:8000/es/user**, sino que busca **localhost:8000/user** y, como el prefijo **locale** está fijado como **requirement** (como se ve en el código), lanza una excepción de ruta no encontrada. Si tecleo **localhost:8000/es/user** a mano, si muestra la página de user.

Como puedo hacer para que el redireccionamiento funcione para todas las rutas, o para un grupo de rutas? Estoy usando Symfony 3.3.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar un default en la ruta, imagino que quedaría así:

```
router:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix: /{_locale}
    defaults:   { _locale: es }
    requirements:
      _locale: es|en|fr|it|pt|de|ca
```